# Не могу настроить перенаправление nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Мой нгинк конфиг

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name server.ru;

    if ($host != $server_name) {
        return 403;
    }    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}


server {

    listen 5000;
    server_name serve.ru;

    if ($host != $server_name) {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Первый участок работает отлчино, по обращению на server.ru, а если по ип выдает 403.

Второй участок работает только по доступу через ип адрес (Возвращает 403)
А по доменному имени (server.ru:5000) просто ничего не происходит . В чем может быть проблема ?

**UPD:**

Замазал реальные даные там где ipv4 там был ийпишник  в4 протокола, там где ipv6 там ип протокола в6 ну и server.ru не настоящее доменное имя

```
root@localhost:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# curl -v http://server.ru:5000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
* Rebuilt URL to: http://server.ru:5000/
*   Trying ipv6...
*   Trying ipv4...
```

Консоль просто залипла и я ее ctrl+c

```
root@localhost:/home/dev/InterExchangeHustla# curl -v http://server_ipv4:5000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
* Rebuilt URL to: http://server_ipv4:5000/
*   Trying 4server_ipv4...
* connect to server_ipv4 port 5000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to server_ipv4 port 5000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to server_ipv4 port 5000: Connection refused
```

Comment: Покажите `curl -v http://server.ru:5000` и `curl -v http://IP:5000`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Добавил в шапку

Comment: Так по вашему логу видно, что и коннект по IP не проходит. Скорее вас не пускает firewall

Comment: @AlexeyTen Так по ип и не должно пускать , там же в конфиге написано что ретурн 403

Comment: В вашем логе нет 403, т.е. `curl` не смог соединиться с nginx-ом. Ошибка `Connection refused` это проблема на сетовом уровне. Обычно это значит, что соединение запрещено файрволлом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забавная штука получилась , у нас используется cloudflare это они блочат все что идет на 5000 порт